# Is there any XML lint maven plugin?

Tags: java, xml, maven-2

I'm trying to validate my XML resources during `maven` build cycle. Is there any plugin for this purpose, or I should use `ant` + `xmllint` manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just have to validate XML files then you can use the [Maven XML Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/).

> The following example would check all
>   files in the directory "xml" for well
>   formedness. Additionally, it would
>   validate all files in the directory
>   "xsd" against the schema
>   "xmlschema.xml".

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>validate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <validationSets>
      <validationSet>
        <dir>xml</dir>
      </validationSet>
      <validationSet>
        <dir>xsd</dir>
        <systemId>xmlschema.xml</systemId>
      </validationSet>
    </validationSets>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Confusion copied as is. `xsd`->`xml`, `xmlschema.xml`->`xmlschema.xsd`